# Перевод из мульти строк в мульти полигоны в postgis

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, postgis

Имеется такие записи в бд:

```
GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(MULTILINESTRING((37.5809998023506 55.7516864604093,37.5809993106367 55.7517142303226,37.5809993459381 55.7518039356441,37.5809956432523 55.7518249057458,37.5809935568758 55.7519563684245,37.5809939159043 55.7519859809325,37.5809848360917 55.7519860159472,37.5809861327819 55.751991965428,37.5809995954065 55.7520946408605,37.5810010861945 55.7521088703071,37.5808452895155 55.7521089713252,37.5808119356862 55.752108535246,37.5807791386048 55.7521085583851,37.5804886026663 55.7521077479809,37.5804653742736 55.7521103256355,37.5803097614377 55.7521092459727,37.5802873921736 55.7521052945213,37.5802723162125 55.752099921048,37.5802603676897 55.7520921093106,37.5802514448501 55.7520818193635,37.5802294404859 55.7520266955935,37.5802351933046 55.7520258166905,37.5802314792867 55.752015380368,37.5802248356546 55.7520161788363,37.5802051816952 55.7519639706355,37.5801979166511 55.7519345303609,37.5801995859011 55.7519257979019,37.5802057796206 55.7519205299362,37.5802127013031 55.7519162803581,37.580200188705 55.7518858196702,37.5801800494502 55.7518883603627,37.5801615387041 55.7518416392379,37.5801562846009 55.7518423389405,37.5801540001485 55.7518348316022,37.5801444806144 55.7518012664946,37.5801387251653 55.7517846337324,37.580427617067 55.751759248305,37.5804265926816 55.7517561309092,37.5805289922005 55.7517476104768,37.5805514410717 55.751747093625,37.5806955778813 55.7517357975439,37.5807069091697 55.7517023918702,37.5809998023506 55.7516864604093)),MULTILINESTRING((37.5809747472676 55.7508877651006,37.5809695931308 55.75088830932,37.580929957223 55.750768682004,37.5809160515004 55.7506829057056,37.5808669372977 55.750683871055,37.5808447804821 55.7504979489028,37.580794523644 55.7504908525948,37.5807662105818 55.7504875251469,37.5807613675684 55.7504869559787,37.5807516399042 55.7504850445253,37.5807423558658 55.7504823151411,37.5807302917583 55.7504769654891,37.5807217477286 55.7504709257718,37.5807156045005 55.7504640196437,37.5807121279859 55.7504565460409,37.5807114686663 55.7504488284625,37.5807136550791 55.7504412009684,37.5807185925826 55.7504339937187,37.5807241259956 55.7504289376741,37.5805803293599 55.7504335500506,37.5805539778536 55.750434395275,37.5802312755889 55.7504444689977,37.5802078863817 55.7504451078525,37.5797898621773 55.7504575175635,37.5798063706006 55.7505808772655,37.5798167946986 55.7506332105047,37.5798228642103 55.7506656201445,37.5798474032153 55.7508085708776,37.5798493940684 55.7508375210576,37.5798526213775 55.750858922901,37.5798650607287 55.7508907359042,37.5798832827931 55.750983191342,37.5798944937045 55.7510335532054,37.580022979525 55.7510298349475,37.5803996172422 55.7510126680666,37.5804602400589 55.7510103200996,37.5805271823624 55.7510088116597,37.5805230209102 55.7509511278252,37.5806377631433 55.7509472354668,37.5807357485022 55.7509439114603,37.580992851082 55.7509327872876,37.5809747472676 55.7508877651006)))
```

Они рисуют некую область на карте, в данном случае рисуется две области этими строками. Как перевести эти строки в полигоны на sql или python?
В конечном виде должно выглядеть примерно так:

```
GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(MULTIPOLYGON((...),(...)))
```

Comment: Полигон, в отличие от мультилинии, замкнут. Вот и развлекитесь, текстовые функции помогут.

Comment: Распарсить и дурак сможет. Неужели стандартных постгисовских функций нету?

Comment: Может, и есть. Попробуйте почитать справку. Но, насколько я помню, там даже извлечения координат одной точки из полилинии - и то нет...